# ios: Centering programmatically edited content in UIButton

Tags: iphone, ios, uibutton, alignment

I have a UIbutton with some centered text in it. When I programmatically update the text, using: `button.titleLabel.text = newValue;` it is no longer centered, instead it has a very strange position (nor centered, nor left-aligned)... how can i make the button update the text to be centered horizontally?

Comment: Also, make sure your text has no stray empty spaces. Try something like `NSCharacterSet *emptySpace = [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]; NSString *trimmedString = [rawString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:emptySpace];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The title of a UIButton should be set using the setTitle:forState: method.

Comment: how do i use this method? i access the button using _button but what is the actual code to use this method?

Comment: `[_button setTitle:@"Some Title" forState: UIControlStateNormal]`.